# force NSDictionary to release memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Somewhere in an ARC project, I have:

```
//Class1.h
@interface Class1 {
    NSDictionary * dict;
}
```

@end

```
//Class1.m
@implementation Class1

-(void)loadDict {
    NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    // Now load couple of (NSString *, NSString *) pairs into the dictionary
    ...
}

-(void)releaseAllMemoryUsedByDict {
    //TODO
}

@end
```

How do I release all the memory occupied by dict, on demand? I guess if I had an NSMutableDictionary, I could call its removeAllObjects method. How would I do it for NSDictionary? Would setting dict = NULL work?

Comment: Setting it to nil will do the job. If its still not working tear all pages of Dictionary :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting it to `nil` will work, assuming that no other object is holding on to (has ***strong*** reference to) the `NSDictionary`.

Comment: ewww, please do not say that.

Answer (score 4):

If you set the `NSDictionary` to `nil`, or any object, it will be released, assuming that no other object is holding a reference to it (**this on an ARC environment**).